# Integração WebService GNRE com C#

Tags: c#, web-service

alguém consegue me ajudar ou já passou por esse problema?

Estou fazendo um projeto para integrar meu software com o webservice da GNRE para enviar as guias de forma automatizada.

Na integração com o Webservice estou enviando o pacote SOAP abaixo, mas estou com a seguinte resposta:

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Estava vendo em alguns posts e me falaram que pode ser também bloqueio de Firewal.

Detalhe, que já tenho o certificado digital da empresa instalado e configurado.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
< soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
< soap:Header>
< gnreCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/webservice/GnreLoteRecepcao">
< versaoDados>1.00</versaoDados>
< /gnreCabecMsg>
< /soap:Header>
< soap:Body>
< gnreDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/webservice/GnreLoteRecepcao">
< TLote_GNRE xmlns="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br">
< guias>
< TDadosGNRE>
< c01_UfFavorecida>PE</c01_UfFavorecida>
< c02_receita>100099</c02_receita>
< c26_produto>20</c26_produto>
< c27_tipoIdentificacaoEmitente>1</c27_tipoIdentificacaoEmitente>
< c03_idContribuinteEmitente><CNPJ>XXXXXX</CNPJ></c03_idContribuinteEmitente>
< c06_valorPrincipal>0.01</c06_valorPrincipal>
< c14_dataVencimento>2015-06-05</c14_dataVencimento>
< c15_convenio>49-Protocolo</c15_convenio>
< c16_razaoSocialEmitente>XXXXXX</c16_razaoSocialEmitente>
< c18_enderecoEmitente>XXXXXX</c18_enderecoEmitente>
< c19_municipioEmitente>50308</c19_municipioEmitente>
< c20_ufEnderecoEmitente>SP</c20_ufEnderecoEmitente>
< c21_cepEmitente>XXXXXX</c21_cepEmitente>
< c22_telefoneEmitente>XXXXXX</c22_telefoneEmitente>
< c34_tipoIdentificacaoDestinatario>1</c34_tipoIdentificacaoDestinatario>
< c35_idContribuinteDestinatario><CNPJ>XXXXXXXXXX</CNPJ></c35_idContribuinteDestinatario>
< c37_razaoSocialDestinatario>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</c37_razaoSocialDestinatario>
< c38_municipioDestinatario>00054</c38_municipioDestinatario>
< c33_dataPagamento>2015-06-05</c33_dataPagamento>
< c05_referencia><mes>06</mes><ano>2015</ano></c05_referencia>
< c39_camposExtras>
< campoExtra>
< codigo>9</codigo><tipo>T</tipo><valor>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</valor>
< /campoExtra>
< /c39_camposExtras>
< /TDadosGNRE></guias></TLote_GNRE></gnreDadosMsg>
< /soap:Body>
< /soap:Envelope>
```

Estou usando o seguinte código C# para a integração com web service:

```
public HttpWebRequest RequisicaoGNRELoteRecepcao()
{           
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create  (@"https://www.testegnre.pe.gov.br/gnreWS/services/GnreLoteRecepcao");
  string file;
  file = @"C:\erp\Certificado.cer";
  X509Certificate cer = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(file);
  webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cer);
  webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
  webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
  webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
  webRequest.Method = "POST";
  return webRequest;
}

public string WebServiceGNREEnviarLote(string arquivo, string xml)
{
  HttpWebRequest request = RequisicaoGNRELoteRecepcao();
  XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();          
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();
  soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xml);
  using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
  }
  using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
  {
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
      string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
      return soapResult;
    }
  }                 
}
```

Comment: Erro 500 é erro interno do servidor. É algum erro do código deles lá.

Comment: Suas tags  estão com espaço (ex:  `< TDadosGNRE>`)? O correto não seria sem espaço `<TDadosGNRE>`? Poste o código c# que usa para enviar o soap.

Answer (score 1):

O erro `500 Internal Server Error` ocorre quando:

- Falha na configuração do servidor
- Uma dependência do servidor parou de funcionar
- Instruções enviadas incorretamente para os headers ou para o corpo do conteudo

Note que o seu SOAP tem espaços no começo de várias tags e isto pode ter ser a causa, como eu disse anteriormente (*Instruções enviadas incorretamente para os headers ou para o corpo do conteudo*), como por exemplo:

`< soap:Envelope`, `< soap:Header>`, `< gnreCabecMsg`, `< versaoDados>`, `< /gnreCabecMsg>`, `< /soap:Header>`, `< soap:Body>`, `< TLote_GNRE`, `< guias>`, etc.

Recomendo que corrija isto.

Uma maneira de enviar SOAP com c# (csharp) é usar algo como nesta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791932/1518921):

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public static void CallWebService()
{
    var _url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/Service1.asmx";
    var _action = "http://xxxxxxxx/Service1.asmx?op=HelloWorld";

    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

    // begin async call to web request.
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

    // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
    // do something usefull here like update your UI.
    asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    // get the response from the completed web request.
    string soapResult;
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.Write(soapResult);        
    }
}

private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    return webRequest;
}

private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
{
    XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
    soapEnvelop.LoadXml(@"CONTEUDO DO SEU SOAP AQUI");
    return soapEnvelop;
}

private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como pediu veja o código .NET que estou usando para enviar a requisição para o webservice e retornando o erro já informado:

Comment: @Alexandre Bom dia, aonde você adicionou o código? Não consegui encontrar, tentou arrumar o XML como mencionei?

Comment: O XML por algum motivo ficou com espaço em branco somente quando postei, porém no meu código está sem espaço.

Comment: @Alexandre você disse tentou adicionar o código .net no comentário? Tente editar a pergunta e adicione lá, nos comentários isto não aparece, grato :)

Comment: public string WebServiceGNREEnviarLote(string arquivo, string xml)
  {
HttpWebRequest request = RequisicaoGNRELoteRecepcao();
XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();   
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();
soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xml);
 using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
    soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
 }
  
 using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
 {using (StreamReader rd = new       StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
     string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
     return soapResult;
    }
   }     
    }

Comment: o erro (500) ok nesse trecho do código acima:                                     using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())

Comment: @Alexandre tentou usar o código que postei?

Comment: não estou usando esse código:

Comment: public HttpWebRequest RequisicaoGNRELoteRecepcao()
{   
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.testegnre.pe.gov.br/gnreWS/services/GnreLoteRecepcao");
string file;
file = @"C:\erp\Certificado.cer";
X509Certificate cer = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(file);
webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cer);
webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
return webRequest;
}

Comment: e para enviar usando o primeiro postado: WebServiceGNREEnviarLote

Comment: já adicionei o código que estou usando na pergunta

Comment: Obrigado por postar o código todo @Alexandre mas você chegou a testar o que postei?

Comment: Aparentemente parece ser igual ao meu código..Acha que se eu usar o código que vc postou poderá resolver o erro 500?Em que ponto acha que está errado?Obrigado.

Comment: Interessante que quando tento acessar o endereço do webservice aparece a mensagem do navegador grome:Sua conexão não é particular.Invasores podem estar tentando roubar suas informações de www.testegnre.pe.gov.br NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. Será que isso também não pode estar afetando minha requisição no webservice?

Comment: Cara conseguiu se conectar no web service ?

Answer (score -1):

O erro está no xml; use o seguinte:

```
const string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
                            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
                                           xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
                                           xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                            <soap:Header>
                            <gnreCabecMsg xmlns=""http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/webservice/GnreLoteRecepcao"">
                            <versaoDados>1.00</versaoDados>
                            </gnreCabecMsg>
                            </soap:Header>
                            <soap:Body>
                            <gnreDadosMsg xmlns=""http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/webservice/GnreLoteRecepcao"">
                            <TLote_GNRE xmlns=""http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br"">
                            <guias>
                            <TDadosGNRE>
                            <c01_UfFavorecida>PE</c01_UfFavorecida>
                            <c02_receita>100099</c02_receita>
                            <c26_produto>20</c26_produto>
                            <c27_tipoIdentificacaoEmitente>1</c27_tipoIdentificacaoEmitente>
                            <c03_idContribuinteEmitente><CNPJ>XXXXXX</CNPJ></c03_idContribuinteEmitente>
                            <c06_valorPrincipal>0.01</c06_valorPrincipal>
                            <c14_dataVencimento>2015-06-05</c14_dataVencimento>
                            <c15_convenio>49-Protocolo</c15_convenio>
                            <c16_razaoSocialEmitente>XXXXXX</c16_razaoSocialEmitente>
                            <c18_enderecoEmitente>XXXXXX</c18_enderecoEmitente>
                            <c19_municipioEmitente>50308</c19_municipioEmitente>
                            <c20_ufEnderecoEmitente>SP</c20_ufEnderecoEmitente>
                            <c21_cepEmitente>XXXXXX</c21_cepEmitente>
                            <c22_telefoneEmitente>XXXXXX</c22_telefoneEmitente>
                            <c34_tipoIdentificacaoDestinatario>1</c34_tipoIdentificacaoDestinatario>
                            <c35_idContribuinteDestinatario><CNPJ>XXXXXXXXXX</CNPJ></c35_idContribuinteDestinatario>
                            <c37_razaoSocialDestinatario>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</c37_razaoSocialDestinatario>
                            <c38_municipioDestinatario>00054</c38_municipioDestinatario>
                            <c33_dataPagamento>2015-06-05</c33_dataPagamento>
                            <c05_referencia><mes>06</mes><ano>2015</ano></c05_referencia>
                            <c39_camposExtras>
                            <campoExtra>
                            <codigo>9</codigo><tipo>T</tipo><valor>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</valor>
                            </campoExtra>
                            </c39_camposExtras>
                            </TDadosGNRE></guias></TLote_GNRE></gnreDadosMsg>
                            </soap:Body>
                            </soap:Envelope>";
```

Na requisição use o seguinte código:

```
 var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Mensagens.WebServiceLoteRecepcao);

            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("SOAPAction:{0}",Mensagens.SoapActionRecepcao));
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(_certificado);
```

Sendo que:

```
Mensagens.SoapActionRecepcao = "http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/wsdl/processar"
Mensagens.WebServiceLoteRecepcao = "https://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/gnreWS/services/GnreLoteRecepcao"
```